# Emails get stuck on send. How do I debug it?

Tags: civimail

I can send emails individually, but bulk emails never seem to work right. I've had no luck troubleshooting it, so I created a test group and added my own contact user to it and verified that it has my email set to home and primary. I created a new mailing to the group and sent it, and it says it started sending, but it hasn't sent anything, and the completed column is still blank. I clicked report on it, and it shows one recipient, but when I click on intended recipients, it says "There are currently no Intended Recipients". So I created another contact with a different email address, added it to the group, and sent another bulk mail. When creating the mail and selecting recipients, it shows the two expected contacts. Then I used "send test to group" to the same group, and both contacts received the test email immediately. So I submitted it, but it still didn't send to either user. The report shows 2 recipients, but when I click to see them, it says there are none. I checked a previously successful email, and it does list the recipients correctly. I turned on debugging, but I guess I don't know how to use it, because it didn't show anything. The scheduled job log shows the same generic success messages down the page, no errors or anything useful. Anybody know what's going on or how I can get some visibility into it? Is there a log file besides the cron log, or is there a way to get more messages into it?

Comment: Do you have flexmailer extension installed?

Comment: Yes, flexmailer is installed and enabled

Answer (score 0):

This is known [issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1717) reported by Andy. Quick fix would to remove the `$mailer->disconnect()` function at [line 77 in src/Listener/DefaultSender.php](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.flexmailer/blob/master/src/Listener/DefaultSender.php#L77) file

Comment: I don't have that level of access currently. Is there an eta on a long term fix?